# Can you daemonize Celery through your django site?

Tags: django, rabbitmq, celery, django-celery-beat

Reading the [daemonization Celery documentation](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/daemonizing.html?highlight=django#usage-systemd), if you're running Celery on Linux with systemd, you set it up with two files:

- /etc/systemd/system/celery.service
- /etc/conf.d/celery

I'm using Celery in a Django site with `django-celery-beat`, and the documentation is a little confusing on this point:

> [Example Django configuration](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/daemonizing.html?highlight=django#generic-systemd-celery-example)
>
> Django users now uses [sic] the exact same template as above, but make sure that the module that defines your Celery app instance also sets a default value for DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE as shown in the example Django project in First steps with Django.

The docs don't just come out and say, *put your daemonization settings in `settings.py` and it will all work out, bla, bla*. From another [SO posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33876932/how-to-properly-daemonize-celerybeat-with-django) this user seems to have run into the same confusion where Django instructions imply you use init.d method.

---

Bonus point if you can answer if it's possible to run Celery and RabbitMQ both configured and with the Django instance (if that makes sense).

I'm thinking not Celery if only because daemon variables include `CELERYD_` and first steps with django say: [*"...all Celery configuration options must be specified in uppercase instead of lowercase, and start with `CELERY_`"*](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/django/first-steps-with-django.html)

Comment: @xtian- Have you tried using supervisor?

Comment: @Stacy, I'm not familiar with it, but the readme here sounded like what I need. But [django-supervisor](https://github.com/rfk/django-supervisor) project has been archived (2 yrs). Is there a fork or other solution under active development you wish to recommend?

Comment: @xtian- I have used https://pypi.org/project/supervisor/ for celery. Worked like a charm.